# Show that $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}f \left( \frac{(1-x)A+xB}{ (1-x)C+xD} \right)$ is decreasing for small enough $x>0$.

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, convex-analysis

How to show that there for small enough $x>0$  the following function is decreasing  in $x$
\begin{align}
g(x)=\frac{1}{x}f  \left( \frac{(1-x)A+xB}{ (1-x)C+xD} \right)
\end{align}
where $f>0$ and $f$ is strictly convex and where $A,B,C,D$ are some real non-zero constants.

When I do Laurent series expansion of the derivative of $g(x)$ around $x=0$ we get that
\begin{align}
g^\prime(x)= -\frac{g(A)}{x^2}  + c+O(x)
\end{align} 
where $c$ is some constnt (see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx%20%20g(%20(1-x)*A%2Bx*B)%2F((1-x)*C%2Bx*D)%2Fx))

Clearly for small enough  $x$ the above object is negative since $g(A)>0$ for any $A$.

Can someone show me a possibly simpler proof or different proof?

Comment: Do you assume that $f$ is smooth, or differentiable?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri I assume differentiability

Comment: May I assume continuous differentiability, os is that too much?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri  Sorry, for being not clear. Yes, please assume continuous differentiability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if $f>0$ then $\lim_{x\to 0^+}g(x) = +\infty$, so the only way your proposal would fail is if $g$ wiggled near $0^+$, which would mean $g'=0$ infinitely often near $0^+$.
Letting

$$h(x) = \frac{(1-x)A+xB}{(1-x)C+xD}$$

we get that

$$h'(x) =  \frac{BC-AD}{{\big(Dx-C(x-1)\big)}^2},$$

so $h'$ has fixed sign, but more importantly is continuous and bounded near $x=0$.
Then

$$g'(x) = -\frac1{x^2}f(h(x)) + \frac1x f'(h(x))\cdot h'(x),$$

so that $g(x)'=0$ for $x>0$ if and only if

$$f'(h(x))\cdot h'(x) = \frac{f(h(x))}{x}.$$

As $x\to 0^+$, the RHS goes to $+\infty$, but the LHS remains bounded, so equality near $0^+$ cannot occur infinitely often.
Therefore, $g$ does not wiggle near $0^+$, and must hence be decreasing near $0^+$.

---

Notice that we did not use $f$'s strict convexity.
We used only the fact that $f$ is continuously differentiable and positive near $h(0)$.
Of course, we need $C\neq 0$ in order for $h'(0)$ to be well defined, but otherwise no conditions on the constants are needed either.

Answer (score 1):

If $x > 0$ is small enough

$$
f\left( \frac{(1-x)A+xB}{ (1-x)C+xD} \right)\approx f\left(\frac{A}{C}\right) = C_0 > 0
$$

hence

$$
g(x) \approx \frac{C_0}{x}
$$

Comment: Thanks. But would like to make these approximations a little more precise.